# RSE is failing to connect, RSEG1066

Tags: eclipse

RSE fails to connect to a previously working ssh host. Host is currently online and sshd is running. No firewalls in-between. Eclipse error log gives RSEG 1066 whenever I attempt to log into remote machine. Other remote machines appear to be working. I have tried restarting, reinstalling, clearing the known_hosts...

Just finished installing 12.04 this morning. Installed eclipse 3.7.2, installed RSE 3.4. RSE was working just fine, but eclipse was not working very well with unity (had alt-tab issues), so I upgraded java using this site's instructions: http://www.duinsoft.nl/packages.php?t=en

Opened eclipse and I was able to alt-tab, but RSE was not able to SSH into the host. Log says RSEG 1066. This is in the report:

```
   eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
   java.version=1.6.0_24
   java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
   BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
   Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86
```

Please help!